# Coloring according to numeric vector doesn't work when using "reorder" in x axis

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart, r-plotly

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# data frame
Title = c('Titanic', 'Avatar', 'Jurassic World')
Profit = c(458672302, 523505847, 502177271)
df = data.frame(Title, Profit)
```

Basically, I'm trying to `color` the bars according to the `Profit` column. And when it's not ordered, it works [figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWNBb.png)

```
# X axis not ordered (working)
plot_ly(df, x = ~Title,
            y = ~Profit,
            color = ~Profit,
            type = 'bar')
```

But when I try to `reorder` the `x axis` (to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV5pH.png)), it returns an **error**, probably because it's a **factor**:

```
# X axis reordered (not working)
plot_ly(df, x = ~reorder(Title, -Profit) %>% as.character(),
            y = ~Profit,
            color = ~Profit,
            type = 'bar')
```

> Error in Summary.factor(c(3L, 1L, 2L), na.rm = TRUE) :
> ‘range’ not meaningful for factors
> In addition: Warning message:
> textfont.color doesn't (yet) support data arrays

Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Works for me, only returns the warning in the post. Could you add your session info?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
  
# data frame
Title = c('Titanic', 'Avatar', 'Jurassic World')
Profit = c(458672302, 523505847, 502177271)
df = data.frame(Title, Profit)
  
# X axis reordered (not working)
plot_ly(df, x = ~reorder(Title, -Profit) %>% as.character(),
        y = ~Profit,
        color = ~Profit,
        type = 'bar')
```

Output:

[image]

This is my `sessioninfo`:

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS 12.3.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] nl_NL.UTF-8/nl_NL.UTF-8/nl_NL.UTF-8/C/nl_NL.UTF-8/nl_NL.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.10.0 ggplot2_3.3.5 dplyr_1.0.8
```

So what you can do is check your session using `sessioninfo()` in your console and check if you packages are right.

Comment: I am using the 4.1.3 version of R. Is that why?

Comment: @FelipeQueiroz, Could be the reason. Also important to check the versions of the packages.